# Java Http server Get Post communication with Javascript Ajax

Tags: javascript, java, ajax, server

Firstly I know javascript is client side. I couldnt find much info on Java server , most of it I found are running tomcat or .jsp.
I have a Java server and a web client. I want to establish some sort of communication using GET POST .
Let say I have a  web form for user to enter their name and click submit, the server will receive it and display out. The form should be feed by the server or the form is at the client side? How is the client to send back the data to the server?

I have place the form in the Server so when the client click request button, the form will be displayed and a text box will appear. My question is how do I get the message enter by the client on the web browser send over to my Java server?

**Java Server**

```
public class JavaHttpServer2 {

  protected void start() {
    ServerSocket s;

    System.out.println("Webserver starting up on port 80");
    try {

      s = new ServerSocket(80);
    } catch (Exception e) {
      System.out.println("Error: " + e);
      return;
    }

    System.out.println("Waiting for connection");
    for (;;) {
      try {

        Socket remote = s.accept();

        System.out.println("Connection, sending data.");
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
        remote.getInputStream()));
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(remote.getOutputStream());

        String str = ".";
        while (!str.equals(""))
          str = in.readLine();

        out.println("HTTP/1.0 200 OK");
        out.println("Content-Type: text/html");
        out.println("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
        out.println("Server: Bot");
        out.println("");

        out.println("<H1>Test Server</H1>");       
        out.println("<form action=\"home\" method=\"post\">" +
                    "<input type=\"text\" name=\"userName\"><br>" +
                    "<input type=\"submit\" value=\"Login\">" +
                    "</form>");



        out.flush();
        remote.close();
      } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error: " + e);
      }
    }
  }

  public static void main(String args[]) {
    JavaHttpServer2 ws2 = new JavaHttpServer2();
    ws2.start();
  }
}
```

**Client**

```
<html>
<body>

<h2>AJAX</h2>

<button type="button" onclick="loadDoc()">Request data</button>

<p id="demo"></p>


<script>
function loadDoc() {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = xhttp.responseText;
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "http://127.0.0.1", true);
  xhttp.send();
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: One would need to write a complete tutorial to fix your code and answer your questions. You should really spend some time understanding how Web apps are working. This tutorial looks basic enough to shred some light on some of your doubts: http://www.codejava.net/java-ee/servlet/handling-html-form-data-with-java-servlet You will need to install Tomcat to be able to follow the examples.

Comment: @Serhiy Does it mean it is impossible to achieve what I want with javahttp server? I know this is capable of doing it with tomcat webservices